# CardView ripple анимация

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Не получается подключить анимацию нажатия на `CardView`, при коде наведенном ниже, анимация присутствует, но не происходит действие, если убрать `android:clickable="true"` действие работает, а анимация пропадает.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/themeCardView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="@dimen/cardview_my_layout_margin"
android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/themeTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:textColor="?attr/editTextColor"
    android:textSize="18sp"/>
```

на данный момент ситуация такая: на API16 анимация есть, на API23 анимации нет.

Comment: ставили логи что пишут ???откладки делали?

Answer (score 0):

А на что у вас слушатель нажатия установлен? Если на внутреннее содержимое - то анимация не будет работать. Она работает для `View`, на которые повешен слушатель нажатий. Должно работать без `clicable` если слушатель повешен на саму карточку. Для этого ей надо id выдать, по ID найти и повесить слушатель.

Comment: слушатель на LinearLayout в котором находится CardView (вставлял код с ним, но почему то именно LinearLayout не показывает в вопросе)

Comment: @МаксимФомичёв, кажется этот LinearLayout у вас лишний. Можно его убрать и вешать слушатель на карточку. Ну или не убирая слушатель на карточку вешать. А не показывается, т.к. не было 4 пробелом от блока кода

Comment: Убрал LinearLayout, повесил слушатель на CardView и значит получил такую ситуацию: на API16 есть анимация, на API23 нет анимации

Comment: @МаксимФомичёв, попробуйте `elevation` убрать

Comment: спасибо, но не помогло

Comment: @МаксимФомичёв, а если просто `?selectableItemBackground` использовать? И/или использовать `background` вместо `foreground`?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52552/discussion-between---and-).

Comment: `android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"` по сути этого должно хватить